# Duplicating web requests between virtual hosts at same server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Let's consider such scenario:

Apache based web server runs Python-based software which gathers data from remote devices through custom HTTP-based protocol. Each time remote device wants to submit some data it composes HTTP query and posts data to the server using address A. A is being realized as SSL enabled virtual host (name based).

At the same physical web server, there is another virtual host which is development snapshot of the production one A - let's call it B. And I want to have each query that is being submitted to A to be duplicated also to B (just to have development database submitted with more realistic data), so basically:

From:

```
[Client] ---> A host
```

To:

```
[Client] ---> A host
         \--> B host
```

So I need to duplicate and send same query to two virtual hosts located at same physical server. The reply from B host can be discarded, it just need to receive original query. The reply from A host should be (as normal scenario) sent to the originating client.

Is Apache's mod_proxy proper direction to solve such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I've heard of anyone trying to mirror traffic in this manner.

But it sounds like it would be better handled at L3/L4 rather than L7 - but this would only work for UDP traffic - as TCP/IP would struggle with the 3-way handshake to two simultaneous destinations.

It seems more obvious to try and do it at your application level, rather than with Apache.